# function .on() not working twice

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have the following code

```
function opacity_on(){      
  jQuery(".wrapper").css({
          'opacity' : 0.4,
          'background-color': 'white',
  });
};

function opacity_off(){     
  jQuery(".wrapper").css({
          'opacity' : 1.0,
          'background-color': 'transparent',
  });
};

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery( "li a.dcjct-slide" ).on( "click focus", opacity_on );
  jQuery( "li.active" ).on( "click focus", opacity_off );
});
```

When I click on `li a.dcjct-slide` `on()` works, but when I click on `li.active` it does not work.

Comment: Do any of the `li` elements have the `.active` class when the events are bound to the DOM nodes? And you seem to be clicking an `<a>` in the first line and an `<li>` in the second. Is that what you meant to do?

Comment: Put a debugger in opacity_off method and see if the method itself is being invoked first.

Comment: Is this what you're trying do do? http://jsfiddle.net/f4K6U/

Answer (score 0):

if I run straight into the console after performing the first function works..

change code to:

```
    jQuery("li a.dcjct-slide").on( "click", function(){

    if(jQuery("#dcjct-1").hasClass("active") ){
       opacity_on();
   }
   if(!jQuery("#dcjct-1").hasClass("active") ){
       opacity_off();
   }   
    });
```

and not work opacity_off() in second click :(